# Artifactory delete all artifacts older than 6 months

Tags: artifactory

How would you delete all artifacts that match a pattern (e.g older than 6 months old) from artifactory?

Using either curl, or the go library

Comment: I'm thinking it could be possible to modify https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/cleanup to do that

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The jfrog cli takes a 'spec file' to search for artifacts. See here for [information on jfrog spec files](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-UsingFileSpecs)

The jfrog cli [documentation is available here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-UsingFileSpecs):

Create an aql search query to find just the artifacts you want:

If your aql search syntax were like:

/tmp/foo.query

```
items.find(
  {
    "repo":"foobar",
    "modified" : { "$lt" : "2016-10-18T21:26:52.000Z" }
  }
)
```

And you could *find* the artifacts like so:

```
curl -X POST -u admin:<api_key> https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/api/search/aql -T foo.query
```

Then the spec file would be

/tmp/foo.spec

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "aql": {
        "items.find": {
          "repo": "foobar",
          "$or": [
            {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "modified": { "$lt": "2016-10-18T21:26:52.000Z"}
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And you would use the golang library like so:

```
jfrog rt del --spec /tmp/foo.spec --dry-run
```

Instead of modified, you can also do a relative date

```
"modified": { "$before":"6mo" }
```

If you get error 405 Method not allowed, verify you have an api or password correct, and try using PUT instead of POST

Comment: Anyway to avoid having to put json query into files?? Just pass text on cml?

Answer (score 2):

Install jforg cli

configure jfrog cli to make API calls

```
jfrog rt c Artifactory --url=https://<>url/artifactory --apikey=<add api key> #can generate api key from user profile
```

Create a spec file called artifactory.spec You can change the find query as required. Below query will

display artifacts from

- registry - docker-staging
- path - *
- download status = null # Not downloaded
- created before 6 month

  ```
  {
  "files": [
    {
      "aql": {
        "items.find": {
          "repo": {"$eq":"docker-staging"},
          "path": {"$match":"*"},
          "name": {"$match":"*"},
          "stat.downloads":{"$eq":null},
          "$or": [
            {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "created": { "$before":"6mo" }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
  ```

You can search for the packages avalable to delete by

```
jfrog rt s --spec artifactory.spec
```

Run the delete command

```
jfrog rt del --spec artifactory.spec
```

Comment: This answer needs update for **jfrog cli 2.0**:
`jfrog config add ArtifactoryName --interactive=false --artifactory-url="https://<artifactory-url>/" --user="<USERNAME>" --password="<API-KEY>"`

Comment: `jfrog rt c` is not supported anymore

Answer (score 1):

We've built a tool for Artifactory artifacts management (cleanup) https://github.com/devopshq/artifactory-cleanup

it'd look like

```yaml
# artifactory-cleanup.yaml
artifactory-cleanup:
  server: https://repo.example.com/artifactory
  # $VAR is auto populated from environment variables
  user: $ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME
  password: $ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD

  policies:
    - name: Remove all files from repo-name-here older then 7 days
      rules:
        - rule: Repo
          name: "reponame"
        - rule: DeleteOlderThan
          days: 7
```

then you should run it to see what it'll remove and when you are ready - add `--destroy` flag to it!

```
artifactory-cleanup
```