# Delete artifacts in artifactory under specified path based on how old they are

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I have a need to delete the artifact versions for one of my repos in artifactory that are older than certain number of days. By this i mean that suppose my artifactory url repo is :-

```html
https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/myrepo/
```

and under that repo there are few folders with the name pattern abc-*-xyz, which means the fully qualified paths here for those folders would be :-

```html
https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/myrepo/abc-1-xyz
https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/myrepo/abc-2-xyz
https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/myrepo/abc-3-xyz
```

Now under each of these folders are stored the actual versioned artifact folders that i would like to only delete, which means that entire version folder for example for two of the urls that would be :-

```html
https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/myrepo/abc-1-xyz/ver_11
https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/myrepo/abc-1-xyz/ver_12
https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/myrepo/abc-2-xyz/ver_3
https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/myrepo/abc-2-xyz/ver_5
```

So based on say if these folders ver_* are older than 30 days, i would like to get them deleted. And only these ver_* folders not abc-*-xyz, etc

I could see the below stackoverflow question and able to get that working for that use case but unable to construct the AQL for my use case so that i can have the spec file accordingly that can be used to delete what i need here.

[Artifactory delete all artifacts older than 6 months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40118550/artifactory-delete-all-artifacts-older-than-6-months)

Any help here to help me get the AQL file constructed and then the spec file that can be called for actual deletion, would be greatly appreciated as always.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following file spec does what you're looking for:

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "aql": {
        "items.find": {
          "repo": "myrepo",
          "path": {"$match":"abc-*-xyz"},
          "name": {"$match":"ver_*"},
          "type": "folder",
          "$or": [
            {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "created": { "$before":"7d" }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The above file spec finds all the folders which match the following criteria:

1. They are under the my-repo repository.
2. They are inside a folder with a name that matches abc-*-xyz and is located at the root of the repository.
3. Their name matches ver_*
4. They were created more that 7 days ago.

To delete all the folders found by this file spec, do the following.

1. Create the file spec and name it as you like. Let's call it *delete-folders-spec* for the sake of this example.
2. From your terminal, run the following JFrog CLI command, while inside the same directory as *delete-folders-spec*

> jfrog rt del --spec delete-folders-spec

Comment: Thanks Eyal. Everything works as you provided in the solution, except for the fact that it doesn't delete anything. So it says [Info] Searching artifacts...
[Info] Found 12 artifacts. and then the command runs forever and actually doesn't delete. Is there anything i am missing for the delete operation in artifactory using AQL?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40118550/artifactory-delete-all-artifacts-older-than-6-months/62676748#62676748

Comment: Answering Ashley's comment above: Could it be that your Artifactory instance uses the default Derby database? If you haven't replaced it with a real database, some search queries are expected to take a very long time to run.

Answer (score 0):

It can be resolved by using --quiet=true in the command as without it it is getting stuck as you can see in the following photo :

[image: asks explicitly for deleting the folders]

Comment: Please do not use screenshots for code or error messages. Instead, I recommend posting the text verbatim in code highlighting format.