# Is there a way to delete artifacts from jfrog artifactory using azure pipelines?

Tags: azure-pipelines, artifactory

I need to delete older artifacts from Jfrog using azure pipelines older than 30 days. Is it achievable through any Jfrog task group?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

The new [JFrog Azure DevOps Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JFrog.jfrog-azure-devops-extension) includes the **JFrog Generic Artifacts** task that allows deleting artifacts in Artifactory using a file spec.

---

If you published builds with these artifacts, and would like to delete the builds with it's artifacts, you can use the [Artifactory Discard Builds task](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Azure+DevOps+Extension#ArtifactoryAzureDevOpsExtension-DiscardingPublishedBuildsfromArtifactory), and check the `Delete artifacts` checkbox.

Otherwise, you can use JFrog CLI's [delete command](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-DeletingFiles) with the [JFrog CLI task](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Azure+DevOps+Extension#ArtifactoryAzureDevOpsExtension-ExecutingJFrogCLICommands).
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40118550/artifactory-delete-all-artifacts-older-than-6-months) as an example to this approach.

Comment: Thanks,this would help me.but where should i place the spec file?

Comment: You can save it anywhere on your filesystem and provide it's path to the command with the `--spec` flag. If you are using a hosted agent, maybe a generic task like powershell can help you create the file.